# How do I get command not found from pipe

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following bash script:

```
exec &>f.log

function f() {
  echo "err: $@"
  exit 1
}
trap 'f' ERR

a=$( aaa --version 2>&1 )
echo $a
```

How do I get 'command not found' message in f.log assuming aaa is not in the $PATH?

Note: 2>&1 is important here, because it's necessary to have $a value in case aaa command succeed (aaa puts its version to stderr if exists).

Answer (score 0):

`$()` captures a commands standard output (but not standard error).

`2>&1` redirects standard error to wherever standard output is pointing at the time (and lets `$()` catch "standard error"  output too).

You've redirected standard output and standard error from the main script to your log file so anything that goes there will get logged there.

You then capture standard error in your `$()` execution (with `2>&1).

If you don't want `$a` catching that output then drop the `2>&1` there and let it fall-through to the earlier `exec` redirect.

Comment: I actually want $a to catch the output (and stderr too) from 'aaa --version' in case 'aaa --version' is executed successfully, otherwise I would like to have 'command not found' and exit 1 caused by trapping the f() function. I also would like everything to go into f.log in any case...

Comment: Unless `aaa` is badly written (which it might be, a number of things are in this way) the output from `--version` *should* go to standard output (and *not* standard error). If that isn't the case here then you can't do what you want without inspecting error codes and output messages and forwarding the error to the output yourself.

Comment: Ok... I'll relveal the details a bit :-)... say, I'd like to check python version instead of 'aaa'. Unfortunately, 'python --version' is printed to stderr instead of stdout on my system. Is this correct that I have no way to implement my use case of capturing 'command not found' message from bash?

Comment: Yeah, that's busted. As is `java -version` I discovered the other day. That should be sent to standard output not standard error as far as I'm concerned. You can't do it without manually checking the exit code (for command not found) or checking the string against "not found" (or similar) and then echoing to the log. You likely should be checking the error code anyway though.

Comment: Oh, that's too bad. I'm using the f() function for other commands in my bash script. With "normal" commands that print out to stdout this doesn't seem to be a problem - I just skip '2>&1' statement and they get caught by trap and I got 'command not found' in the log, so no need to check for exit status upon failure. Will check for exit status explicitly for this use case - thanks for letting me know about that!

Comment: "command not found" in your logs doesn't stop your script or let you report on that failure specifically. It just logs that it happened and you are left to deal with an empty value. Checking for failure exit status means you can take meaningful action. You should likely be doing that anyway to be able to handle the failures and do something meaningful.